# How can I select an exact image using Sikuli in webdriver

Tags: java, sikuli

I have  written Sikuli code(in java) for the images taken from the flash. And Sikuli is not able to select the exact image, whereas it just clicks on any other picture when that image is not to be selected.

Comment: It is not clear what are asking. Please give a complete description of what you want to achieve, what you've done, what you expect and what is not working.

Comment: Hi, have I answered your question? If no could you explain what you're currently having issue with; otherwise you mark the answer as correct to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is asking entirely however here is a snippet on how you can create patterns and use them to interact with your environment.

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C:\some\path\image.png").similar(0.8f);
Region region = screen.exists(pattern);
region.click(pattern);
```

You can set the 'tolerance' level that Sikuli has to abide by using `Pattern#similar` incase you notice Sikuli interacting with a differnt image on the screen. You would also be able to set the target's offset should you wish to click on different parts of the pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C:\some\path\image.png").similar(0.8f).targetOffset(100,5);
```

Just to give you an example. Provide us more information with what you have tried so far so that we can assist you further. Do note that it's best to just keep images within the same directory just so you can call it through its relative path.

```
Project
   |
   |_ src
   |   |_ package
   |        |_ testsikuli.java
   |
   |_ imgs
       |_ image.png
```

Allows you to generate a pattern like so - `Pattern pattern = new Pattern("imgs/image.png")` which is much easier. Also, if you wish to export it as a runnable JAR, make sure that the `imgs` directory is kept wherever the runnable JAR has been exported aswell.